# Python "onkeypress" implementation

Tags: python

I am trying to use "onkeypress" It's a simple code which  creates a ball that goes forward and backwards but it only goes forward. I am doing this on Visual Studio Code.

```
import turtle
import time
global  i
i=False
wn=turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("white")
wn.setup(width=600,height=600)
x=turtle.Turtle()
x.left(90)
x.shape("square")
x.color("black")
x.penup()


def start():
   i=True


wn.onkeypress(start,"w")
wn.listen()
wn.update()
if i==True:
  x.forward(100) 
wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: I am sorry It's just goes forward

Comment: Namespaces. Every function has its own namespace with its own `i`.

Comment: Because you don't have code to make it go in other directions. You only have `x.forward(100) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a simple mistake. When your code runs it reads the `if i==True` statement observes that `i=False` and reaches end. When you press 'w' although you have changed the variable to True but it has nothing to do after changing as the if statement has already passed.

What you can do instead is just put the movement statement inside the function you attached with `onkeypress`

Something like this.

```py
import turtle
import time
global  i
i=False
wn=turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("white")
wn.setup(width=600,height=600)
x=turtle.Turtle()
x.left(90)
x.shape("square")
x.color("black")
x.penup()


def start():
   x.forward(100)


wn.onkeypress(start,"w")
wn.listen()
wn.update()

wn.mainloop()
```

Hopefully this will help.

Comment: Thank you so much. Silly me  how  I couldn't see that.

Comment: Remember to mark your questions answered by the tick arrow if they satisfy the query

Answer (score 0):

you have only used `x.forward(100)` if you want it to go in multiple directions, you need to have more code for each direction i.e `x.left(100)`